# Puppeteer & cycling a process through multiple users

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape information from a webpage behind a login wall for two users. As it stands, I've managed to get the code to do what I want for the first user i.e. go to webpage, login, gather the links associated with properties in a saved list, use that list to gather more details and log them to console.

The challenge I have now is getting the code to loop this round the second user without having to dupe the code. How would you suggest I go about it?

Secondly I need to make the array for each user, declared as `uniquePropertyLinks` in the below, accessible outside of the function userProcess.

How can I produce a new array for each user?

How can I access the array outside the function?

Here is the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//Code to locate text and enable it to be clicked
const escapeXpathString = str => {
  const splitedQuotes = str.replace(/'/g, `', "'", '`);
  return `concat('${splitedQuotes}', '')`;
};

const clickByText = async (page, text) => {
  const escapedText = escapeXpathString(text);
  const linkHandlers = await page.$x(`//a[contains(text(), ${escapedText})]`);
  
  if (linkHandlers.length > 0) {
    await linkHandlers[0].click();
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Link not found: ${text}`);
  }
};

//User credentials
const userAEmail = 'abc@hotmail.com';
const userAPassword = '123';
const userBEmail = 'def@hotmail.com';
const userBPassword = '456';
  
//Logout
const LogOut = async (page) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.website.com');
  await clickByText(page, 'Log out');
  await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});
  console.log('Signed out');
};


/////////////////////////// 
//SCRAPE PROCESS
async function userProcess() {
  try {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless : false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setUserAgent('BLAHBLAHBLAH');

  //Go to Website saved list
  await page.goto('https://www.website.com/shortlist.html', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  console.log('Page loaded');

  
  //User A log in
  await page.type('input[name=email]', userAEmail, {delay: 10});
  await page.type('input[name=password]', userAPassword, {delay: 10});
  await page.click('.mrm-button',{delay: 10});
  await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'})
  console.log('Signed in');

  //Wait for website saved list to load
  const propertyList = await page.$$('.title');
  console.log(propertyList.length);

  //Collecting links from saved list and de-duping into an array
  const propertyLinks = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sc-jbKcbu'), e => e.href));
  let uniquePropertyLinks = [...new Set(propertyLinks)];
  console.log(uniquePropertyLinks);

  //Sign out
  LogOut(page);

} catch (err) {
    console.log('Our error - ', err.message);
  } 
  
};

userProcess();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see some of the things you might need to complete your task. I think it's better to take time and develop the skills yourself, but I can perhaps point out a few key things.

You use:

```js
const userAEmail = 'abc@hotmail.com';
const userAPassword = '123';
const userBEmail = 'def@hotmail.com';
const userBPassword = '456';
```

but then you're talking about looping. With such a data structure, it will be difficult to loop these two users. I recommend putting it into an object like so:

```
const users = {
    a: {
        email: 'abc@hotmail.com',
        password: '123',
    },
    b: {
        email: 'def@hotmail.com',
        password: '456',
    },
};
```

then you can easily look with for example `for .. in`:

```js
for (const user in users) {
    console.log(users[user]);
}
```

or with `.forEach()`:

```js
Object.values(users).forEach(user => {
    console.log(user);
});
```

> need to make the array for each user, declared as uniquePropertyLinks in the below, accessible outside of the function userProcess.

Then declare the array outside of the funtion:

```js
let uniquePropertyLinks = [];

async function userProcess() {
    // you can access uniquePropertyLinks here
}

// and you can access uniquePropertyLinks here as well
```

> How can I produce a new array for each user? How can I access the array outside the function?

Again, it'd be better to choose a differen data structure, let's day an object with keys that would represent each user and values would be arrays. It'd look like so:

```js
let uniquePropertyLinks = {};

uniquePropertyLinks.a = [];
uniquePropertyLinks.b = [];
```

which looks like this:

```
{ a: [], b: [] }
```

so you can save whatever values for user a into `uniquePropertyLinks.a` array and whatever values you need into `uniquePropertyLinks.b` array:

```js
uniquePropertyLinks.a.push('new_value_for_a_user');
```

similarly for user b.

Now you should have all the bits you need in order to go back to your code and make the necessary changes.

Comment: Thanks @pavelsaman, I’ve started to implement this and it’s working. I hadn’t come across structuring data as properties of an object before!

Also just want to thank you for how you’ve answered this question, you could have gone about it by updating my code but instead you’ve given advice. This is far more helpful in helping me learn so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the results of pavelsaman's advice below is the updated code:

```
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//Object storing user credentials
let userAEmail = 'abc';
let userAPassword = '123';
let userBEmail = 'def';
let userBPassword = '456';

const users = {
  userA: {
      email: userAEmail,
      password: userAPassword,
  },
  userB: {
      email: userBEmail,
      password: userBPassword,
  },
};

//Object storing users saved lists as arrays
const usersPropertyLinks = {};

usersPropertyLinks.userA = [];
usersPropertyLinks.userB = [];


//Function to retrieve users saved list of properties
async function retrieveUserSavedList(users, usersPropertyLinks) {
  try {

    //Load broswer
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless : true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setUserAgent('BLAHHBLAHHBLAHH');
  
    for (const user in users) {

      //Go to saved list
      await page.goto('https://www.website.co.uk/user/shortlist.html', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
      await page.waitForSelector('.mrm-button');

      //User log in
      await page.type('input[name=email]', users[user].email, {delay: 10});
      await page.type('input[name=password]', users[user].password, {delay: 10});
      await page.click('.mrm-button',{delay: 10});
      await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'})
      console.log('Success: ' + users[user].email + ' logged in');

      //Collecting saved property links and de-duping into an array
      const propertyLinks = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.sc-jbKcbu'), e => e.href));

      //Add saved property links to an array for each user
      if (users[user].email === userAEmail ) {
        usersPropertyLinks.userA.push(...new Set(propertyLinks));
      } else if (users[user].email === userBEmail ) {
        usersPropertyLinks.userB.push(...new Set(propertyLinks));
      } else {
        console.log('problem saving links to user array');
      };

      //Sign out
      await page.click('.sc-kAzzGY',{delay: 10});
      await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'});
      console.log('Success: ' + users[user].email + ' logged out');
    };

    browser.close();

} catch (err) {
    console.log('Error retrieve user saved list - ', err.message);
  } 
  
};

//Run the code
retrieveUserSavedList(users, usersPropertyLinks);
```